# WPF: Access SelectedItem of nested DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a nested DataGrid setup. How do I access the SelectedItem for the inner grid?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OuterGrid}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ..... />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding InnerGrid}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInner}">
                <DataGridTextColumn ..... />
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

`SelectedInner` is a property and even if I select a row in the `InnerGrid` in the UI, that property is still null.
How do I know which row was selected in the inner grid? I also use caliburn-micro.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the '`SelectedInner`' object is in your ViewModel. If the the object is in your ViewModel of your view (as is in the example below), you need to use `RelativeResource` in order to point out the datagrid where your bound object is.

```
class ShellViewModel:Screen
{
    public BindableCollection<DataGridObject> OuterGrid { get; set; } = new BindableCollection<DataGridObject>();
    public BindableCollection<DataGridObject> InnerGrid { get; set; } = new BindableCollection<DataGridObject>();

    public DataGridObject selectedInner { get; set; } = new DataGridObject();

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        OuterGrid.Add(new DataGridObject {String1="water",String2="air",String3="earth" });
        OuterGrid.Add(new DataGridObject {String1="water1",String2="air2",String3="earth2" });
        OuterGrid.Add(new DataGridObject { String1 = "water3", String2 = "air3", String3 = "earth3" });
            
        InnerGrid.Add(new DataGridObject {String1="water",String2="air",String3="earth" });
        InnerGrid.Add(new DataGridObject {String1="water1",String2="air2",String3="earth2" });
        InnerGrid.Add(new DataGridObject {String1="water3",String2="air3",String3="earth3" });

        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => OuterGrid);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => InnerGrid);
    }

    
}

public class DataGridObject
{
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }
    public string String3 { get; set; }
}
```

On the xaml you need to use `RelativeResource`

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OuterGrid}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible">
        <!--<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn />
        </DataGrid.Columns>-->
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.InnerGrid}" SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.selectedInner}" >
                    </DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Make sure you specify the correct ancestor which ma be `window` or `usercontrol`

Comment: Usually the InnerGrid Binding is a property of the Outer DataGridObject (and the inner Object can be different from the outer one). Nevertheless, the RelativeSource Binding of the SelectedItem is what solves the problem.